# 301 Moved Permanently while running Jenkins Build from Slack

Tags: nginx, jenkins, slack-api

Following [this](https://sonnguyen.ws/how-to-trigger-a-jenkins-build-from-slack/) tutorial, I want to include a slash command in Slack which will remotely trigger a Jenkins build.My Jenkins server being reverse proxy using ngnix.

So, the command `https://[Jenkins-Server]/buildByToken/build?job=[job-name]&token=[token]` triggers a build when ran using `curl` or my browser.
The `curl` output is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 12 Aug 2015 08:51:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 11
Connection: keep-alive
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

But the following output is given, when it's trigger via Slack. I have embedded the same URL while integrating the slash command.

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I am very new to slack, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please check your http log to make sure that you are using a correct Token

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing *where* you're being redirected to, it's hard to tell whether this is normal or bad behaviour.

Are you being redirected to a login page, for example?

Have you checked in the reverse proxy access logs which URL is *actually* being called by your Slack command?